# Nullable type in WebApi 2 autogenerated documentation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

When the endpoint in my WebApi is returning class like

```
public Class1
{
    public int Property1{get;set;}
    public int? Property2{get;set;}
}
```

in the autogenerated documentation both `Property1` and `Property2` appears as **integer**. Is there a way to force the documentation indicate that `Property2` is `nullable`?